# Lambda filter not working as expected

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm using this lambda expression in my code:

```
File slika = new File(tempPath + File.separator + imena.stream().filter(x -> !x.trim().equals("null")).findFirst().get());
```

It's supposed to get a name from a file that was posted to my servlet that doesn't equal null. I checked the contents of the `ArrayList<String> imena`, and found out that it contains the following (separated by commas): null, null, null, Photo0098.jpg. The last one is the one I posted to the server, and the one that is supposed to get picked up by the filter, but instead I get a null pointer exception. That identical piece of code works on another servlet that also handles file uploads. Can someone tell me why my code is not working here, even though it works elsewhere in the same condition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the value in the list is an actual `null`, not a string with the content of `"null"`. Using a method reference to [`Objects.nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-) is an elegant way of filtering them out:

```
File slika = 
new File(tempPath + 
         File.separator + 
         imena.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().get());
         // Here --------------^
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought that the String itself was called null because in my upload dir I ended up with a file called null and the other file I posted. Filtering out the real nulls solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your element `x` is null. When you trying to trim your `string` occurs your `NullPointerException`.

Try this

```
File slika = new File(tempPath + File.separator + imena.stream().filter(x -> x != null).findFirst().get());
```

Answer (score 1):

Trimming the existing String never returns `null` since it contains anything to trim, else it would throw NullPointerException first. Filter directly the `null` values out.

```
imena.stream().filter(x -> x != null).findFirst().get();
```